# Matplotlib not plotting at all correctly, not seen anyone else have this issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I'm trying to code with matplotlib, so that it plots coordinates of the majority of cities in the USA on a graph. As should be evident by the fact I'm asking this question, it isn't working. The code is just plotting all the points on a single diagonal line, shown below, and both axises are completely out of order (you can see it clearly on the y-axis). Below is both an image of the result, and the matplotlib code I'm using:
[Image of multiple points on a single diagonal line with no order to either axises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW0v4.png)

Code:

```
def demand(places, distfact):
  demandList = []
  fig = plt.figure()
  print(len(places))
  for origin in places:
    for destination in places:
      if origin != destination:
        dist = haversine(float(origin.lat), float(origin.lon), float(destination.lat),
                     float(destination.lon))
        result = (int(origin.population) * int(destination.population)) / (dist * distfact)
        line1 = [origin.name, destination.name, result,
             [origin.lat, origin.lon], [destination.lat, destination.lon]]
        line2 = [destination.name, origin.name, result,
             [destination.lat, destination.lon], [origin.lat, origin.lon]]
        if line2 not in demandList and result >= 75000000 and dist >= 30.0:
          demandList.append(line1)
  demandList.sort(key=lambda row: (row[2]), reverse=True)
  for i in range(0, 20):
    print(demandList[i][0], "->", demandList[i][1], ":", "{:,}".format(demandList[i][2]))
  print("\n")
  print(len(demandList) - 30, "routes")
  print("\n")
  for i in range(0,10):
    ind = len(demandList) - i - 1
    print(demandList[ind][0], "->", demandList[ind][1], ":", "{:,}".format(demandList[ind][2]))
  for i in range(len(demandList)):  
    xpoints = np.array([demandList[i][3][0], demandList[i][4][0]])
    ypoints = np.array([demandList[i][3][1], demandList[i][4][1]])
    plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints, "o")
```

"places" is a list of objects. Each object contains a townID, name, population, latitude and longtitude. distfact is simply a number, in this example it's set to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as I can't see what's in your variables: try casting the values from your x_points and y_points variables to whatever makes sense in your case be it float or int. It seems to me that they are seen as strings by pyplot.

edit: Not a guess anymore, you're missing casts to float, when populating line1 with latitudes and longitudes. You do do it in your haversine computations but not three lines below.